# Git error: Not a git repository - even though I see the git folder

Tags: git, repository

`fatal: Not a git repository(or any of the parent directories): .git`

Why do I get the above error even though I see the git folder in my project

I have just tried looking at git status in my project and I got the error above. The folder is in there and it works okay but the git seems to be not found at all.

Does anyone know how I can fix this at all? Currently crying in my hands on this at the moment.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Could you have had hard disk failures? Do you have a clone of the repository somewhere? If you have a clone, you would be able to recover by cloning the clone, and copy your files from lost clone over it and commit. You would lose any history not pushed from your working repo to the clone, but that would probably be just a few commits.

Comment: I created a branch called 'Staging' and then inside this I created a remote repo with beanstalk. I then pushed to beanstalk to deploy the site and in beanstalk got an error like so: `No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'vendor/php-instagram-api/php-instagram-api'`. Would this have something to do with it?

Comment: I don't know, are you using submodules? I haven't used them myself, so I'm not quite sure. Nevertheless, does the `git status` error appear even if you are in the root of your repository? (For example, maybe you are calling it from inside one of the submodule directories?) Also, check your .gitmodules file for any error. Could you have mistakenly added `.` or some other thing to it?

Comment: I am in my root where I set the git repo up at the start. I also cannot see a .gitmodules file at all.

Comment: So is php-instagram-api a submodule? Perhaps you need to set it up in `.gitmodules` then?

Comment: It's a library in laravel! Would this solve the issue of the repo not working or not allowing any git commands